# IBM Worklight 6.0 - How to read event data used in a Geo trigger?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-geolocation

I have one Geo trigger and I want to read the data placed in event property of that trigger.

How can I read this data before my application sends the event data alongwith devicecontext to the server? Is there any way to send few parameters to my callback function?

```
  var trigger1 = {
              type: "DwellInside",
              circle: {
                longitude: 88.41, 
                latitude: 22.58,   
                radius: 100000 // 100km
              },
              dwellingTime: 100,
              confidenceLevel: "high", // high confidence that we are in the circle
              callback: this.myFunction,
              eventToTransmit: {
                event: {
                  city: "data.city"   // dynamically added using JSON data.
                },
                transmitImmediately: true
              }
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

The callback function only receives back the device context when the trigger fires.
If you'd like additional information, you could code it for example into a "wrapper" function - for example:

```
callback: function(deviceCtx) { myFunction("data.city", deviceCtx); },
```

Comment: I am getting this error- "Exception thrown from trigger callback: ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined"

Comment: and the function looks like this- myFunction:function(data,ctx) { console.log(data); },

Comment: is there any way to read the whole event data that is sent by the application to the server as a transmission buffer ? coz I can see, that includes everything i.e. deviceContext as well as the addition data.

Comment: The event does include the deviceContext at the moment of capture (the same data that is passed to the callback function). This can be used as part of an event handler (see WL.Server.setEventHandlers API), or for analytics.
There isn't any way on the device to read the event data before it gets sent to the server.

Comment: yes...I don't see any way to read the event data but I think Worklight API developers must consider adding this feature in the callback function.